# Keeping rownames when using setDT()

Tags: r, r-rownames

I have a data frame where:

```
df <- data.frame(row_id = c(100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109),
     row_id2 = c(1000,2000,3000,4000,5000,6000,7000,8000,9000,10000),
     col1 = c(1,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0),
     col2 = c(1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0),
     col3 = c(0,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,0),
     col4 = c(1,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,1),
     col5 = c(1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1))
```

I transpose the table and use `rownames` to get:

```
library(data.table)
df_tr<-transpose(df)
rownames(df_tr)<-colnames(df)

|       |  V1    V2    V3   V4   V5   V6   V7   V8   V9   V10 |
|row_id |  100   101  102  103  104  105  106  107  108   109 |
|row_id2| 1000  2000  3000 4000 5000 6000 7000 8000 9000 10000|
|col1   |    1     0    1    1    1    0    0    1    1     0 |
|col2   |    1     1    1    0    0    1    1    1    0     0 |
|col3   |    0     0    1    0    0    1    1    1    1     0 |
|col4   |    1     1    1    0    0    1    0    1    1     1 |
|col5   |    1     1    1    0    1    0    1    0    0     1 |
```

I later need to use `setDT(df_tr)` so I can use `sapply()`, but by doing `setDT(df_tr)`, I lose my `rownames`.

Is there a way where I can keep my `rownames` using `setDT()`? My end goal is to keep my rownames after converting it to a data.table so my `df_tr` has rownames when I use `sapply()`.

Comment: Like dww I find the aim strange- what are you doing that means you want sapply()? Why wouldn't keeping it in its original shape work?

Comment: @rg255 i need to keep the transposed version because in the dataset im using (i didn't include this part in the example) i need to use one of the columns for sliding windows. that's why i want to find a way to keep the rownames in the transposed version

Comment: But you can do a sliding window the other way too, check out functions like lag() and shift()

Comment: @rg255 i think i tried doing that at first, but the column i need to use for sliding windows has values at varying intervals, ex. 1111, 1234, 2465, 3512

Answer (score 2):

data.table does not use row names.  Instead you can retain them as a new column

```
setDT(df_tr, keep.rownames=TRUE)
#         rn   V1   V2   V3   V4   V5   V6   V7   V8   V9   V10
# 1:  row_id  100  101  102  103  104  105  106  107  108   109
# 2: row_id2 1000 2000 3000 4000 5000 6000 7000 8000 9000 10000
# 3:    col1    1    0    1    1    1    0    0    1    1     0
# 4:    col2    1    1    1    0    0    1    1    1    0     0
# 5:    col3    0    0    1    0    0    1    1    1    1     0
# 6:    col4    1    1    1    0    0    1    0    1    1     1
# 7:    col5    1    1    1    0    1    0    1    0    0     1
```

You can then use this id column in a more canonical data.table style for any grouping, sorting, filtering etc. that you need to do.

That said, I do find your data structure to be a bit strange and may not be optimal for your task.  Typically, each column of a table would contain many rows of the same type of data. Not knowing your specific use case, it is hard to be certain, but I am unconvinced that transposing the table like this would be the best solution for you.